# pytorch slow loading speed on dataloader

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying this code.

https://github.com/Dannynis/xvector_pytorch/blob/master/xvector%20-%20gpu.ipynb

in this code, I changed to this:

```
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(list(zip(X,y)), shuffle=True, pin_memory=True, batch_size=256, num_workers=8)
```

and it took very long (~23s) for one step:

```
loss: 1.8956436561879668 step took 23.29119372367859
```

I think it is related to this code, copy 256 vectors to cuda took so long?

```
for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
    a = time.time()
    # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
    inputs, labels = data
    inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()
```

I wonder if there is anything I can do to speed up the data_loader?

Comment: Does this happen on every batch that is loaded or just one time in the beginning? The first time any cuda related function is called the whole cuda context and everything related to it is initialized, which can take some time.

Comment: every patch. thx.